# Writing and retrieving files from NSDocumentDirectory iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to download a file(pdf, doc, docx etc) in NSFileManager from some specific URL. Later on when user taps on same link I want to retrieve the file from NSFileManager. Here is the code I've done:

```
    - (void)checkIfFileExist {

    NSString *path1;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path1 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Content-Directory"];
    path1 = [path1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];
    NSLog(@"The read path is %@", path1);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path1])
    {
        //File exists
        NSData *file1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path1];
        if (file1)
        {


        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fzs.sve-mo.ba/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf"];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSString *path;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Content-Directory"];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];
        NSLog(@"The written path is %@", path);
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                contents:urlData
                                              attributes:nil];
    }
}
```

Now here every time I'm trying to fetch the file from file manager the condition that file exists always returning me FALSE. The paths where I'm writing and reading the file are same as I've checked them on console. Any mistake that I've done?

Comment: Post your code for saving the file.

Comment: @Avi : it is there. the else condition.

Comment: Did you check whether writing is successful?  Does the file appear in the sandbox?  You can check via the Devices window in Xcode.

Comment: I think you need to monitor the status of the  **createFileAtPath** function. It is return boolean for success or fail.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];}
```

after

```
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Content-Directory"];
```

in your else part and replace

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:urlData attributes:nil];` with `[urlData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```